# bootstrap button color not coming correct on chrome (Machine Mac)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I needed a grey color for my button so I used button of bootstrap and it helped me achieve my goal. The problem is when I view it on chrome on a mac machine it show white color background rather then grey.

Can anybody shed some light on it

```
<button class="btn btn-sm" style="font-weight: bold;color: #3f51b5; width: 100px;border: solid 1px black;" data-id="xxxxxxx" data-phase="" data-phases="xxxxxx" data-description="" data-priority="0" data-due="" data-name="TTTTe" data-status="complete" data-assigned="xxxxxx" data-target="#project_actions" onclick="editTask(this,'xxxxxx')"> Edit</button>
```

**Chrome (Linux):**

[image: Grey color coming]

Grey color coming which is my goal

**Chrome (Mac):**

[image: White color coming]

White color coming which I want to change to grey

Please help me out I can't figure out what is the reason I'm getting a white color on chrome on a mac machine

Comment: try `background-color:#3f51b5`

Comment: @Lyubomir that way it is working but I want to know why am I seeing different color on chrome on a mac machine

Comment: Because of different defaults. not sure what else there is to say. If you want something to come out the way you want, don't rely on defaults. Font family, font size, character encoding etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. I was able to find a solution for it. For mac, we have to use `-webkit-text-fill-color`

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it using `style='-webkit-appearance: none!important;'` . It's working now.